# Error throwing for user field populated through Views: Filter by an entity reference view

Tags: views, entities

I am working on a ticket system in my current project (Drupal 8) where user can assign a ticket to particular user. The user field is populated through entity reference and it is filtered using 'Views: Filter by an entity reference' (users belonged to a particular role need to be shown there). For normal users its resulting in 500 Internal server error. It works perfectly if I give 'Administer users' permission to current user role. But without that it will break. I have given 'view user information' permission to all users. Is there any work around without giving 'Administer users' permission to all users as it is not a viable option.

Comment: Anyone else sees this please reference https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/301176/any-idea-why-drupal-8-view-field-empty-when-executing-a-view-of-user-emails-by

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the users from a particular role you don't need to rely on views filter option. Default method is enough, there will be an option to filter the users using roles. I know its the answer that you are seeking. But its a work around. But if you need to add other filter parameters this method will not be enough.